# Update SSRS security for reports

Tags: reporting-services, report

I am looking to update the SSRS security on reports. I have been asked to tidy up the reports . Is there a query that can do this for me on sql server?

Comment: 'tidy up the reqorts' is a vague requirement. please add some technical detail about what is the goal. what do you mean with 'update the SSRS security on reports'?

Comment: Sorry if i'm abit vague. I have no experience so i might come accross vague at times. Okay so at work we have a database called Alpha and in it are secured reports. I have been asked to create a new security folder and delete the old security on each report. So that all the reports can get security from the new security folder. Now i can do this manually or do it on sql server.

Comment: Please do not edit your question with a totally different one. Edit the question only if you want to add details, or clarify the question. If you have another question, then ask a new question.

Comment: I tried to ask a new question but i was not allowed to do that so i was left with no choice but to edit the question.

Comment: Were you able to delete the security settings?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to update the security settings:

**With a query**

> Note: This is not supported

First, you have to understand the following concepts:

- The `Catalog` table contains the Reporting Services items (reports, folders, ...)
- The security information (called `Policy`), is located in the `PolicyID` column of the `Catalog` table
- The user rights are called `Roles` and are stored in the `Role` table
- The users are located in ... wait for it ... the `Users` table
- The `PolicyUserRole` table links a `User`, a `Role` and a `Policy`

And last but not least, by default an item inherits the security settings from the parent folder. If you change it, a new `Policy` will be created.

What you want to do is locate the security setting GUID you want to use:

```
SELECT * FROM [Catalog] WHERE [Path] = '/NewFolder'
```

Then, apply it to all the elements you need.
Here is an example for the children items:

```
UPDATE [Catalog] SET [PolicyID] = '<NewFolderPolicyID>' WHERE [Path] LIKE '/NewFolder/%'
```

**Manually**

> Note: the following applies if you don't have a lot of items or if you
>   have plenty of time to spend.

Change the Parent folder security settings. As stated above, all the elements in the folder where the inheritance has not be broken will automatically use the parent settings.

Then, browse reports and choose "Revert to Parent Security" in the security options for reports having settings different than the parent report.